# Select statement within select statement SQL and access

Tags: sql, select, nested

I am trying to select the maximum price of a product that has been sold within the database, I have three tables (`tbl_CarForSale`, `tbl_Commision` and `tbl_Salesman`).

What I want to do is select the Maximum price of a Car that has been sold, and then, using that record, be able to calculate the commision earned, and link it to the salesman. I have the following and it returns the Maximum car price, but I don't know how to directly use the returned record to get the other information possible.

```
SELECT Max(tbl_CarForSale.carprice)
FROM (SELECT tbl_CarForSale.*, tbl_Salesman.*,  from tbl_CarForSale, 
WHERE bolSold = true)
```

I am guessing that I would need to put this into another `SELECT` statement and nest it, but I am not sure how to do this.

Edit:

As requested the field names are here.

```
tbl_salesman: name
tbl_CarForSale: registration, soldDatem salesmanNo, carPrice, bolSold
tbl_Commision: minValue, maxValue, comAvliable
```

Basically, the idea behind the Commission table is that a salesman earns commission based on the price of the car, and therefore I have a query that looks at the car price and will return how much commission the salesman has earned

Comment: Can you show more details about your 3 tables to help figure out which fields need to be in the SQL?

Comment: Your schema is not clear. How do you link between `tbl_salesman` and `tbl_CarForSale`? perhaps a missing id field on the salesman table. And also, how do you calculate the commision?

Comment: The commision is calculated by taking the CarPrice (in tbl_carForSale) and selecting the comAvliable where the carPrice is between minValue and MaxValue.

the relationship is 1 -> many where one salesman sells one car? I don't understand why you would want another field within the salesman table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
select your fields
from your tables
where bolSold = true
and tbl_CarForSale.carprice = (select max(carprice) from tbl_carForSale)
```

Comment: Is it really that simple?? I will give it a go now, thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: @user2186566 accepting his answer will give him positive rep too.

Answer (score 0):

`tbl_salesman` needs to have the `salesmanNo` attribute too that way the tables have a like attribute to join on. That goes for the other tables, as well.

What's bolSold do?

If I'm understanding correctly, `tbl_Commision` doesn't make sense as a table, but rather a function or handled at application level with a couple special queries.

This should give the maximum price of a car sold by each salesman if the `salesmanNo` was included in `tbl_salesman`.

```
SELECT salesman.name, MAX(tbl_CarForSale.carprice) FROM tbl_salesman JOIN tbl_CarsForSale GROUP BY salesman.name ORDER BY MAX(tbl_CarForSale.carprice);
```

You could add a `WHERE` clause at the end of that to specify greater than and less than constraints or you can create a function and replace the `MAX()` function in example above with newly created one.

It also might make sense to normalize a bit. I don't know your exact requirements, but I would consider something like this:

```
car: registration, carPrice, bolSold
salesman: salesmanNo, name
sold_record: date, salesmanNo, registration REFERENCES car.registration,salesmanNo REFERENCES salesman.salesmanNo
```